# Ad units Div-ids frequently changing

Tags: id, ads, adsense

I have a strange issue with my website, the div-ids frequently changing for AD units. How to make them static?

I copy the code from the Google ad unit and paste it to my site but the Div-ids frequently changing.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: That's probably Google changing them.

Comment: How can you explain?

Comment: Well if Google is providing the semantic code for the ads, including the DIVs, then it's probably generating the IDs.  So different AD, different ID.  If you're attempting to target them, see if there is a class name that is consistent instead.  Or wrap the whole thing in a 'container' DIV and target that.  You didn't provide any code or even all that much information so it's hard to explain WHAT exactly is going on, I'm just offering a hypothesis based on the little info you offered.